# Animated show: Mechs in space and an annihilating super weapon

Tags: story-identification, tv, space

I watched it in the 90's on Cartoon Network or Fox Kids or something like that. There was a space fleet (with a mothership of course), and there was a team of people, each of whom piloted one "mech" (big, anthropoid robot) while exploring and fighting on various planets. I have a vague memory of one mech being piloted by someone like Jubilee from the X-Men cartoon, and another by someone like Captain Nick Fury (the white one) from the animated Spider-Man - but that is probably my faulty memory.

In one episode a kind of super weapon was activated. It was an orange field that grew from the generator ship and annihilated (or maybe just stopped) every ship in sight.

That is all I can remember. (I don't think it was Japanese - but that is only a hunch)

Comment: sounds like one of the gundams

Comment: Could also be powerangers, in space

Comment: Do these characters look familiar? http://www.gameranx.com/img/15-Sep/exo-squad.jpg If so, it's ExoSquad. This is just a guess based on your description of the characters resembling those from the Marvel cartoons.

Comment: Yes, this is it, thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be describing Exo Squad:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exosquad

From Wikipedia (emphasis added):

> ***Exosquad*** is an American **animated television series** created by
>   Universal Cartoon Studios as a response to **Japanese anime.** The show
>   is set in the beginning of the 22nd century and covers the
>   interplanetary war between humanity and Neosapiens, a fictional race
>   artificially created as workers/slaves for the Terrans. The narrative
>   generally follows Able Squad, an elite Terran unit of **mecha pilots**, on
>   their **missions all over the Solar System**, although other storylines
>   are also abundant. The series ran for two complete seasons in
>   **syndication from 1993 to 1994**, and was cancelled after one
>   third-season episode had been produced.

[image: Exosquad http://www.gameranx.com/img/15-Sep/exo-squad.jpg]
Able Squad in action.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thanks :)

Comment: The Superweapon you describe is a weaponized form of a "Graf-Shield", a gravity powered defensive device invented by Doctor Algernon while the Neosapiens held him captured on Venus.